# How do I substring piped output from grep in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, cygwin, piping

I'm trying to write a script to login to a Drupal website automagically to put it into maintenance mode. Here's what I have so far, and the grep gives me back the line I want.

```
curl http://www.drupalwebsite.org/?q=user | grep '<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*" value="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"  />'
```

Now I'm kind of a Linux newbie, and I'm using Cygwin with BASH. How would I then pipe the output and use a command to get the value of the id attribute from the output that grep generated? I'll be using this substring later to do another curl request to actually submit the login.

I was looking at using expr but I don't really understand how I would tell expr "oh hey this stdin data I want to you manipulate in this way". It seems like the only way I could do this would be by saving off the grep output in a variable and then feeding the variable to expr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` to trim the results you get from your `grep`, ie.

**edit** : added myID variable, use any name you  like.

```
myID=$( 
  curl http://www.drupalwebsite.org/?q=user \
  | grep '<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*" value="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"  />' \
  | sed 's/^.* id="//;s/" value=.*$//'
)


#use ${myID} later in script
printf "myID=${myID}\n"
```

The first part removes the 'front' part of the string, everything up to the `id="`, while the 2nd part removes every `" value= ....`.

Note that you can chain together multiple sub-replace actions in `sed` by separating them with the ';'.

**edit2**
Also, once you're using sed, there's no reason to use grep, try this:

```
myID=$( 
  curl http://www.drupalwebsite.org/?q=user \
  | sed -n '\@<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*" value="form-[a-zA-Z0-9]*"  />@{
       s\@^.* id="@@
       s\@" value=.*$@@p
   }'
)
```

( It's a good habit to get into to removing unnecessary processes. It may not matter in this case, but if you get to where you are writing code that will be executed 1000's of time in a hour, then having an extra grep when you don't need it is creating 1000's of extra processes that don't need to be created.)

You may have to escape the '< and >' chars like '\< >' or , worst case '[<] [>]'.

I'm using the '@' as the reg-ex replacement separator now to avoid having to escape any '/' chars in the srch-target string. And I continue using it in the whole example, just to be consistent. For some seds you have tell them that you're using a non-standard separator, hence the leading \@ at the front of each block of sed code.

The -n means "don't default print each line of input", and because of that, we have to add the 'p' at the end, which means print the current buffer.

Finally, I'm not sure about your regular expression, particularly the `-[a-zA-Z0-9]*`, this means zero or more of the previous character (or character class in this case). Typically people wanting at least one alpha-numeric, will use `-[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*`, yes OR `[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*`, but I don't know your data well enough to say for sure.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jazzepi see edits. Added example to show you how to ' use[ing] this substring later to do another curl request'. Good luck.

Comment: Perfect! Works great. Thanks! Also thanks for the extra bit. I do actually know how to store variables but I appreciate the extra step there.

Comment: @Jazzepi Glad that helped. No see edit2. We don't even need grep (But I don't have a way to test this, as I don't have the output from curl to test with). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `grep` again with the `-o` option. Possibly two consecutive `grep`s to also filter out the surrounding `id="..."` part.

```
   -o, --only-matching
          Print only the matched (non-empty) parts  of  a  matching  line,
          with each such part on a separate output line.
```

Comment: I tried using -o on the original grep, and it matches the entire line, so that's what it gives you back. I also need it to match the entire line. I can't be terribly permissive because I don't want style changes elsewhere in the page to make grep return some junk. The problem with using -o this way is that you have to provide some context to the * and when you do, that context gets returned when you use -o so this will never trim the way I'm talking about.

Comment: What I was thinking was something like: `echo '<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-ajkldj23j" value="form-lkaj9823"  />' | grep -o 'id="form-[[:alnum:]]*"' | grep -o 'form-[[:alnum:]]*'` This echoes an example output from your `curl | grep` command, through two new greps which first filter out the `id` attribute, then filters away the surrounding `id="..."` garbage. That's how I interpreted your question. :-)